# Wordpress Function to add URL Parameters to iFrame

Tags: wordpress

I am struggling to add custom parameters to an iframe in Wordpress

I have an iframe of http://www.iframeurl.com - to this iframe url I need to add in the current logged in users email. and then add an md5 hash of the current date to act as a password.

http://iframeurl.com?user=user@email.com&password=md5hashofcurrentdate

Anyone know the best way of going about this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Put all of this in your functions.php file.**

```
function wp_54885505_get_user_iframe_url(){
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if( ! empty( $user->user_email ) ){
      //create the url
      $url = 'http://iframeurl.com/?user='. $user->user_email .'&password=' . md5( date('d/m/Y') );
      return $url;
  }
}

function wp_54885505_display_iframe(){
  $src = wp_54885505_get_user_iframe_url();
  if( ! empty( $src ) ) : ?>
      <iframe src="<?php echo $src ?>" />
  <?php endif;
}

add_shortcode( 'user_iframe', 'wp_54885505_display_iframe' );
```

Call `[user_iframe]` on the wordpress page you wish to display the iframe on.

Comment: That is fantastic - works like a charm, and have learnt alot from this - thank you very much.

Comment: I have ran into a problem - how would i call this function so it displays the iframe link within a template page. I can call it fine but it prints the link instead of showing the page.

Comment: Just call the second function wherever you want your iframe to show up.

Comment: yes I have been trying that but it prints out the full url string rather than displaying the iframe.

I am very rusty on wordpress, have tried wrapping it to a shortcode too but still only prints out the text rather than display the destination iframe. It is something daft I am overlooking as it is 99.9% there.

Comment: Where are you trying to display the iframe?

Comment: I am trying to display the iframe within a wordpress page.

Comment: I'd edited my awnser to meet your needs, simply copy and paste everything in your functions.php file and use the user_iframe shortcode on the page you want the iframe on.

Comment: aahh thank you i have been scratching my head trying to get it to work much appreciated.